# How can I take this kitchen faucet apart?

Tags: repair, kitchens, faucet

The hot water on my kitchen faucet recently started dripping. I haven't a clue what make or model it is, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to take it apart to get at the seat and springs. Can anybody help identify it or give my some hints on where I might find a model numbers, so I can find instructions to take it apart? Or, any suggestions on how to get it apart?

[image: The faucet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pfister Hanover 2-Handle, Pull-Down Kitchen Faucet](http://www.pfisterfaucets.com/kitchen/product/hanover-2-handle-pull-down-kitchen-faucet-f-531-4tms)

[Instruction sheet](http://s7d1.scene7.com/is/content/Pfister/32691-0400)

I'd include some actual instructions here, but it's spelled out in the linked sheet. Have a look at that.

Comment: The instructions suggest that I just need to rotate the hub in a counterclockwise direction. It's way too tight for me to do this by hand, at least not without a wrench or something. But I am afraid a wrench will damage the finish. Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried to get a hand grip on the hub with a friction rubber gripper, such as one which is used to open jars? Failing that, there are 'strap' wrenches with a Kevlar reinforced rubber strap which should do the job without scratching the finish.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of those round rubber jar opener and if that doesn't work, go to your Harbor Tool store and purchase a rubber strap wrench.  At Harbor, it is sold as a set of three and relatively inexpensive.  Use the one that fits.  Also, try spraying some WD-40 penetrating oil at the base so it loosens the thread (don't get any on the upper part; only the base). The rubber strap wrench won't damage the finish.  This worked for me.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.